# Error after installing Apache Airflow

Tags: python, linux, pip, airflow

I have installed Apache airflow using the command `pip install airflow`. When I try to access airflow by typing `airflow` , getting the below error.

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 4, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 29, in     <module>
    from airflow import configuration as conf
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 433
     ('core', 'sql_alchemy_conn'),
                            ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found that `airflow.cfg` file is missing. I have uninstalled and reinstalled airflow and Still getting this error. Could anyone suggest a solution? The OS is RHEL6.7.

Comment: That's not the full error; that arrow is referring to something, but you haven't shown what. Please post the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have added the missed out line.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really enough information to go on, but I suspect the problem is that you are using Python 2.6; the library is probably only compatible with Python 2.7.

Comment: I have python2.6 as default and I have altinstalled Python2.7.

Comment: Well you need to use Python 2.7 when you install the library. Perhaps `python2.7 -m pip install airflow`, depending on how it is installed.